# Add column with median absolute deviations (MADs) per row

Tags: r, dataframe, row, median

I have the following `data.frame`. I would like to add a column to the left, which lists the median absolute deviations (MADs) per row (I am using the `stats` package). I have read posts using the `rowMeans` function, but I cannot use it here for the MAD. I hope someone can help, please.

```
 library(stats)
 df <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol=7, nrow=3, 
    c(3,6,NA,4,5,NA,7,6,2,7,10.4,8,9,NA,3.7,4,6,0.4,NA,7,2.9), byrow = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop over the rows with `apply`, `MARGIN = 1` and apply the `mad`

```
df$MAD <- apply(df, 1, mad, na.rm = TRUE)
df$MAD
#[1] 1.48260 2.22390 2.29803
```

---

In `matrixStats`, there is `rowMads`

```
library(matrixStats)
rowMads(as.matrix(df), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 1.48260 2.22390 2.29803
```

Answer (score 1):

We can write our own function in base R to calculate median absolute deviation (MAD).

```
my_mad <- function(x, constant = 1.4826) {
    median(abs(x - median(x, na.rm = TRUE)), na.rm = TRUE) * constant
}

apply(df, 1, my_mad) 
#[1] 1.48 2.22 2.30
```

Comment: Awesome alternative! Thank you! :)